# Get-ChildItem Visualizer

Tags: powershell

Does anyone know of a way to visualize (via a GUI) Get-ChildItem output?  I'm working on a couple scripts that will build up a listing of all the files on our NAS, compare it with the last run, and spit out just the files that have changed but I'm having a hard time visualizing the data and have to run custom `| where-object {}` every time we want a report on the data.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is pertaining more toward getting GUI output, a quick and dirty method is to pipe to `Out-GridView`. It will launch in a WPF window.

Comment: I was looking for more of a graph than a table.